# parametric function plotting in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot x = cos(u)*cos(v), y=cos(v)*sin(u), z = -sin(v) where u,v both are from (0,\pi). I looked at `fplot3` function but it takes only one parameter. Can anyone point to some function or is there some other way like writing a script to do the plotting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`fsurf`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fsurf.html) for parametric surface plots. `fsurf` accepts two inputs, `u`, and `v`.

```
% your functions
f_x = @(u,v) cos(u).*cos(v);
f_y = @(u,v) cos(v).*sin(u);
f_z = @(u,v) -sin(v);

% plot
umin = 0;
umax = pi;
vmin = 0;
vmax = pi;

figure(1); clf;
fsurf(f_x,f_y,f_z, [umin umax vmin vmax])
```

[image]

You can also check out `fcontour` and `fmesh`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know about `fsurf`. Cleaner solution as the one I suggested. +1!

Answer (score 2):

I would use `meshgrid` for this:

```
u = linspace(0,pi,51);
v = linspace(0,pi,51);
[U,V] = meshgrid(u,v);
X =  cos(U).*cos(V);
Y =  sin(U).*cos(V);
Z = -sin(V);
```

Then you can plot it as a mesh (using `mesh(X,Y,Z)`) or as a set of lines (e.g., shown here via `plot3(X',Y',Z')`), as you like:

[image: Plotted via mesh]
[image: Plotted via plot3]